# Use of ob_start() and ob_get_clean()

Tags: wordpress, buffer

I usually code like this:

```
$output .= 'custom code';
    $output .= 'another line of custom code';
$output .= 'more code';     

return $output;
```

Now I want to use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_get_clean()`. 
What's the most effective way to use it inside my example?

Answer (score 9):

This will return the same as your example given :

```
ob_start();
echo 'custom code';
echo 'another line of custom code';
echo 'more code';
return ob_get_clean();
```